# How to show category list from firestore in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I have a product named collection,
In that product collection I have saved products with their name and category. Now I need to create a tab bar with all the category list inside products. The problem is there are multiple products with same category. And I want that category to be shown once. How to achieve this?

This is my code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products') .where("category").snapshots(),
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');

    if (snapshot.hasData) {

      final docs = snapshot.data!.docs;

      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, i) {
          
          final data = docs[i].data();
          Set s = {};
          s.add( data["category"]);
          
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(s.elementAt(0).toString()),
            
          );
        },
      );
    }

    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must provide ur code ,

guessing this code will help u to implement ur code....

here I have taken Movie instead of product..U may correct it based on ur requirement...

```
class Movie {
  String name;
  String category;
  String language;
  int rating;

  Movie(
      {required this.name,
      required this.category,
      required this.language,
      required this.rating});
}

void main() {
  List<Movie> movielist = [
    Movie(name: 'Golmaal', category: 'Comedy', language: 'Hindi', rating: 5),
    Movie(name: 'Naseeb', category: 'Classic', language: 'Hindi', rating: 5),
    Movie(name: 'Hera Phery', category: 'Comedy', language: 'Hindi', rating: 5)
  ];

  final categories = movielist.map((e) => e.category).toSet();//this will generate unique category list..

  print(categories);
// now use this categories to ur design with listview or any list widgets
}
```

Comment: my data is saved in firebase collection